# how would i make this send as an embedded message

Tags: python, discord, embed

I am making a selfbot and have this

```
@knife.command()        #
async def howgay(ctx, member:discord.Member):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await ctx.send(f"{member.mention} is {random.randint(0,101)}% gay")
```

i would like to make it so it send the message as an embed

Answer (score 1):

To send an embed with a bot, you need to use an embed() function.
There are 4 arguments in an embed() function: title, url, description, and color.
An example:

```
@client.command()
async def embed(ctx):
    embed=discord.Embed(title="Sample Embed", url="https://stackoverflow.com/", description="This is an embed that will show how to build an embed and the different components", color=0xFF5733)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

As you can see, the 4 arguments in order are used in the syntax above.

Title: First line of text

Url: click on the title, and it will bring you to the url entered

Description: the text below

Color: Colour hex code

By the way, to use a custom color, you can copy the hex code from a website and paste it.